# Export the Excel Range into PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using this below code to save the range as pdf but it does not save it as pdf neither gives an error.

```
Sub ExportAsPDF()
'Variables
Dim SaveRng As Range
Dim pdfname As String
Dim path As String

'Setting range to be saved
Set SaveRng = Sheet2.Range("A1:D13")

'setting file name with a cell value
pdfname = Sheet2.Range("C1")

'path
path = "C:\Users\Jamini\Pictures"

'save the range as pdf
SaveRng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:=path & pdfname & ".pdf"


End Sub
```

Comment: Try inserting the path separator as `Filename:=path & "\" & pdfname & ".pdf"`. Or build the path ending in path separator, in this way: `path = "C:\Users\Jamini\Pictures\"`.

Comment: ^^ your pdf is probably in "C:\Users\Jamini" with the name Pictures and whatever you have in C1.

Comment: I have checked the relevant folders but nothing is there @Warcupine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try inserting the path separator as:

```
Filename:=path & "\" & pdfname & ".pdf"
```

Or build the path ending in path separator, in this way:

```
path = "C:\Users\Jamini\Pictures\"
```

And Warcupine is right, I think. You should find the created pdf in "C:\Users\Jamini" folder, **but named as** `"Pictures" & pdfname & ".pdf"`...

Comment: Thank you very much. Alright i understand the point now thank you.